# Why would an offset function that successfully defines a range in name manager generate an error when that name is referenced by a graph?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a function entered in the name manager that is as follows:

=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(10,1,1,1)), rowOffset, startColumn + StartYear - firstColumnYear-1,1,yearsOfData+1)

It is a formula that will dynamically update a line plot of investment market values between two years that are selected by the user. When I select the entry in name manager, I can see that excel clearly makes the correct selection but when I try to enter the name in an excel graph, excel says "We found a problem with one or more references in this worksheet". I have no idea what the problem I am running into is caused by. I have used similar methods in the past to make dynamic graphs without issue. Thanks for any help you can provide and let me know any other info I can offer to help find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as if you try to be sheet-independent with your name and `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(10,1,1,1))`. This is not possible for charts. If you replace the INDIRECT Part with `Sheet1!$A$10` in your name definition, then it should work. In this example Sheet1 is the sheet where the data for the chart are.

The reason is, there is no ThisSheet for the chart from which it can get its data. Even not the sheet, the chart is placed on. The chart can be placed on a sheet but it can also be placed in a separate chart sheet. So the data definition has to be complete with sheet and range.

Further there seems to be a second problem. INDIRECT with ADDRESS not works for names for chart series. So if the goal is to have the start address dynamic, we have to construct it with string concatenation in INDIRECT. Because

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$10"),1,1,1,5)
```

works.

Comment: Thanks Axel. That makes sense. What is happening when I try to add a sheet name to the address function? Ex: =ADDRESS(10,1,1,1,"Sheet1"). Shouldn't this work because it is no longer sheet-independent? I still get the same error when I apply it to the graph though.