# Named Range in Excel Graphs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a named range that uses an offset formula to define a dynamic range. The offset formula works correctly (i.e. when I go into the Name Manager and click on the name/formula it highlights/references exactly what I want it to). The formula is named RANGE and is shown below:

```
  =OFFSET(INDIRECT('Sheet1'!$B$2),0,0,'Sheet1'!$F$6+1,1)
```

The issue I am having is using it in a graph as one of my data series. I have tried both of the following when defining the series values and neither work. I have tried Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering what is below thinking it may have to do with Excel not recognizing it as an array, but that also did not work.

```
   ='Workbook Name.xlsm'!RANGE
   ='Sheet1'!RANGE
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious. This should not be that difficult.... Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In addition, I have other graphs in my workbook that do the EXACT same thing and they work fine....

Comment: B2 contains the address to a cell on the same sheet. F6 is the number of rows down I want to include in the selection. So the selection starts in the cell indicated by B2 and contains a few cells below it (as indicated by F6).

Comment: Your cell Sheet1!B2 should contain the sheet name too in its string value. Like "SheetN!XY123" and not only "XY123" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412254/why-would-an-offset-function-that-successfully-defines-a-range-in-name-manager-g/27421858#27421858

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Axel, that was helpful and was one issue but there was also another one too. The second issue was the sheet name itself - it was two words and it appears once I concatenated the name to one string as it should have been it worked fine.

Comment: I would rename your RANGE into something like aRANGE, or chartRANGE so Excel doesn't potentially misunderstand your use of the word for an actual range... even though it refers to one